# Ktor Client not showing all response headers

Tags: kotlin, ktor-client

So i am building a web application with ktor and using it to make requests to my backend, is some request i want a response header, but ktor is not catching this headers.

In postman and in the dev tools the headers appers

Bellow my ktor client and a request exemple:

```kotlin
private val client = HttpClient(Js)

    suspend fun get(accessToken: String, refreshToken: String): Response<User> {
        return try {
            client.get {
                url("${Urls.BACKEND_SERVICE}/user")
                header(RequestHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, "application/vnd.kaiqkt_user_v1+json")
                header(RequestHeaders.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, RequestHeaders.BEARER_PREFIX.plus(accessToken))
                header(RequestHeaders.REFRESH_TOKEN_HEADER, refreshToken)
            }.let { response ->
                when (response.status) {
                    HttpStatusCode.OK -> {

                        updateLoggedIn(response.headers)

                        Response(
                            data = mapper.decodeFromString<User>(response.bodyAsText())
                        )
                    }

                    HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized -> {
                        Response(
                            error = Error(
                                type = ErrorType.UNAUTHORIZED,
                                message = response.bodyAsText()
                            )
                        )
                    }

                    else -> Response(
                        error = Error(
                            type = ErrorType.UNEXPECTED_ERROR,
                            message = response.bodyAsText()
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            throw ex
        }
    }
```

Ktor catches the response headers Authorization and Refresh-Token